# add graph to htm webpage using perl

Tags: perl

I have created a graph and i need to  somehow incorporate HTML to display the graph , i have added the html part to my code but it gives me gibberish data in my html page.

the graph itself prints is correct when i see the gif image
here is my code

```
#!/pkg/qct/software/perl/5.20.0/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;
use GD::Graph::lines;
use Text::ParseWords;
use CGI qw(:standard);

my $input_file  = $ARGV[0];
my @data =  read_data_from_csv($input_file);

my $my_graph = new GD::Graph::lines($graph{'width'}, $graph{'height'});

$my_graph->set(%config); 
$my_graph->set_legend(@legends);

$my_graph->plot(\@data);


my $ext = $my_graph->export_format;
open( count_out, ">tabel.html" ) or die "cant open out $!";
print count_out "<HTML>";
print count_out "<head>";
print count_out "</head>";
binmode STDOUT;
print count_out $my_graph->gd->$ext();
print count_out "</table>";
print count_out "</body>";
print count_out "</html>";
close(count_out);

sub read_data_from_csv
{
    my ($fh) = @_;
    my @d = ();

    open(FH, "<$fh") || die "Error: no open for $fh: $!";
    while (<FH>) {
        chomp;
    next if ($. == 1);
        my @row = parse_line($delimiter, $keep, $_);
        for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#row; $i++) {
            undef $row[$i] if ($row[$i] eq 'undef');
            push @{$d[$i]}, $row[$i];
        print "@{$d[$i]}\n"; # $tf1[1] is the second column and $tf1[2] is the third column
        }
    }
    close (FH);
    return @d ;
}

%graph = (
    width => 1400,
    height => 1400,
);

%config = ( 
    width         => 1400,
    height        => 1400,
    title         => 'Die size and transistor count per block',
    y_min_value   => '0',
    y_max_value   => '300',
    y_tick_number => '20',
    y_label_skip  => '2.5',
    x_ticks       => 0,
    long_ticks    => 0,
    x_label_font_size =>22,
    xlabelheight => 50,
    x_labels_vertical => 1,
    x_label_color => 'black',
    x_label_font => 'Times 25 {normal}',
    legend_placement => 'RT',
    legend_marker_height => 20,
    transparent   => 0,
    bgclr         => 'white',
    dclrs => [ qw(black blue green red) ],
);

@legends = (
    'Die Size',
    'Transistor Count',
);
```

can somebody please tell what is wrong with code for the html part

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't work like that.

Your image is a binary data file. You can't (easily) just embed binary image data into an HTML document. If you look at pretty much any web page that includes an image, then that image will be stored in a separate file and then added into the main HTML page using the `<img ...>` tag. That's the approach you should probably take.

1. Generate your image and store it in a file.
2. Add an `<img>` tag to your HTML which uses your image file as its `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

thanks

i used the  and src attribute to the image on my html page ...but it comes at the top ....i already have somethings in the html and I need this image at the bottom ... how can we do that .

this is the command i added to the above code to get the image to  the html

```
print count_out "<img src='/usr2/mydata.gif'>";
```